# How can I cascade the location where new windows are opened up?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm currently opening a new window with this:

```
var v = new View()
{
    Owner = this,
    WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen
};
v.Show();
```

However, if the user tries to open up multiple windows, they just stack on top of each other.  Is there something obvious I'm missing to cascade them so that they are all somewhat visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working:

```
var v = new View()
{
    Owner = this
};
var ownedWindows = OwnedWindows.Cast<Window>().Where(w => w.IsVisible).ToList();
if (!ownedWindows.Any())
{
    v.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
}
else
{
    v.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
    v.Left = ownedWindows.Max(w => w.Left) + 20;
    v.Top = ownedWindows.Max(w => w.Top) + 20;
}
v.Show();
```